# How to access router globally in backbone js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, singlepage

This is my app.js file. I need to access the router's `navigate` method from within the `navigateToLogin` method of the `LandingView` class. But since the appRouter is defined after the view it can't recognize the router from within the view. So I need to find a way to globally access the router from any class or method. How can I get around this problem?

```
var LandingView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div', 
    id: 'landing',
    className: 'landingpad',
    events: {
        'click button#login': 'navigateToLogin',
    },
    render: function (){

        (this.$el).append("<button class='button' id='login'>Login</button><br/><br/><br/>");
        (this.$el).append("<button class='button' id='new'>New User?</button>");

        console.log(this.el);
        return this;
    },
    navigateToLogin: function(e){
        app.navigate("/login", true);
        return false; 
    },
});

var appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

initialize: function(){
    $('#content').html(new LandingView().render().el);
}
});

    app = new appRouter();
```

Comment: Lukas's answer should be the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you dig into Backbone's code a little, you'll notice that the router's implementation of `navigate` in turn calls `Backbone.history.navigate`:

```
// Simple proxy to `Backbone.history` to save a fragment into the history.
navigate: function(fragment, options) {
  Backbone.history.navigate(fragment, options);
}
```

So instead of explicitly mucking up the global scope, use `Backbone.history.navigate`:

```
var LandingView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    navigateToLogin: function(e){
        Backbone.history.navigate("/login", true);
        return false; 
    },
});
```

Comment: I solved the navigation problem. I omitted the slashes in the navigate function and it worked :) But thanks for the info. Its interesting to learn that there is always more than one way to solve a problem :)

Answer (score 7):

If you need `appRouter` to be accessible globally, you have to attach it to some global object. In web browsers this is the `window` object.

```
window.app = new appRouter();
```

And access it via window:

```
window.app.navigate(...);
```

Using globals can lead to code that's difficult to maintain. If your app is not of trivial size, consider using some decoupling mechanism, such as the [mediator pattern](http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/#mediatorpattern).

Comment: Well I'm making a small app which is quite manageable and purely for educational purposes. It worked. Thanks :)

Comment: ` routes:{
 "" : "init"
 "/login": "loadLogin",
 },`
My router doesn't seem to trigger the loadLogin function of my router. Is there anything wrong with the above statement?

Comment: @jaykumarark not sure, try defining the route without the leading forward slash.

Comment: Anyways thanks for the help. I think there is probably some syntax error. I ll look into it :)